# how to set up JRE home in STS when i am using java11

Tags: windows, spring-tool-suite, java-11

i am trying to migrate java 6 application to java 11 so my intial step was to setup JDK 11 in STS but i see starting from jDK 9 oracle has stopped bundelling jre inside JDK so when i try to set the path in JRE home i am getting the error as "Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found" and i am using window 10

tried different JDK version's starting from jdk 9 till jdk 8 all works fine as we have jre bundled in JDK

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer myself tried to use the latest STS and pointed the jre home to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.5" and this works .